# Probability to be able to get your holidays when you want

Tags: probability

I'm looking for a way to calculate the probability to be able to get your holidays when you want based on:

- There are $365$ days in the year
- Weekends will be counted as normal days (to simplify)
- You can take $20$ days holidays
- There are $x$ number of persons taking $20$ days holidays and you can not take the same days

My guess is that for one person it will be $$\frac{(365-20)}{365}=0.945$$ and for $x$ number of persons will be $$\frac{(365-(20*x))}{365}$$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=$total employees.

Let $y=$number of employees who have already chosen their days.

The probability of any position in order of picking vacation days, i.e first, second, third... is $\frac{1}{x}$

The probability of getting the days you want is a function number of people who have picked before yourself.$$\frac{365-20*y}{365}$$
You had the right function, except the variable represents the number of people whom have already chosen vacation days, not the total amount of employees.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer. This formula could end up with negative values. Is it correct to say that when 20*y>365, then the probability is zero?

Comment: It is probably more likely you wont get a negative value, assuming the company didnt say everyone gets 20 days and there is like 20 employees.